# ClassCastException when running CDI+JSF 2.2.1 on Wildfly

Tags: jsf, jboss7.x, cdi, activiti, wildfly

I have a webapp which deploys a simple [Activiti](http://www.activiti.org/) process,some JSF pages and CDI Beans.

Everything works on JBOSS AS 7.1.1 + JSF 2.1.7. However I need to use JSF 2.2, so I tried to configure it on AS 7, but I stumbled on some errors described in [this jboss forum post](https://community.jboss.org/thread/203257). Bottomline: AS 7 and JSF 2.2 do not work together very well. So I tried to get my app up and running with Wildfly.

The startup went on without any relevant errors or warnings. However, upon navigating to a specific jsf page I got an ulgy exception:

```
12:00:20,894 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-8) Error Rendering View[/taskForm_newOrder.xhtml]: javax.el.ELException: /taskForm_newOrder.xhtml @18,51 value="#{bookOrder.isbn}": java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.weld.context.SerializableContextualFactory$PassivationCapableSerializableContextual cannot be cast to javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:115) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:115) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:115) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1896) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:451) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:87) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:136) [undertow-websockets-jsr-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:136) [undertow-websockets-jsr-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationCallHandler.java:52) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:65) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:70) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextCreationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextCreationHandler.java:54)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:207) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:194) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:72) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:128) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpHandlers.executeRootHandler(HttpHandlers.java:36) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:628) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.weld.context.SerializableContextualFactory$PassivationCapableSerializableContextual cannot be cast to javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:368) [javax.el-3.0-b07.jar:3.0-b07]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140) [javax.el-3.0-b07.jar:3.0-b07]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204) [javax.el-3.0-b07.jar:3.0-b07]
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226) [javax.el-3.0-b07.jar:3.0-b07]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.0.3.Final.jar:2013-07-17 09:29]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.0.3.Final.jar:2013-07-17 09:29]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.weld.context.SerializableContextualFactory$PassivationCapableSerializableContextual cannot be cast to javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean
    at org.activiti.cdi.impl.context.BusinessProcessContext.get(BusinessProcessContext.java:56) [activiti-cdi-5.9.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.context.PassivatingContextWrapper$AbstractPassivatingContextWrapper.get(PassivatingContextWrapper.java:61) [weld-core-impl-2.0.3.Final.jar:2013-07-17 09:29]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:76) [weld-core-impl-2.0.3.Final.jar:2013-07-17 09:29]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79) [weld-core-impl-2.0.3.Final.jar:2013-07-17 09:29]
    at org.bpmnwithactiviti.cdi.bean.BookOrder$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getIsbn(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363) [javax.el-3.0-b07.jar:3.0-b07]
    ... 72 more

12:00:20,911 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-8) Servlet request failed HttpServerExchange{ GET /book-cdi-app-1.0/taskForm_newOrder.jsf}: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.jboss.weld.context.SerializableContextualFactory$PassivationCapableSerializableContextual cannot be cast to javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:87) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:136) [undertow-websockets-jsr-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:136) [undertow-websockets-jsr-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationCallHandler.java:52) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:65) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:70) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextCreationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextCreationHandler.java:54)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:207) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:194) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:72) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:128) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpHandlers.executeRootHandler(HttpHandlers.java:36) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:628) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Beta7.jar:1.0.0.Beta7]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.weld.context.SerializableContextualFactory$PassivationCapableSerializableContextual cannot be cast to javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean
    at org.activiti.cdi.impl.context.BusinessProcessContext.get(BusinessProcessContext.java:56) [activiti-cdi-5.9.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.context.PassivatingContextWrapper$AbstractPassivatingContextWrapper.get(PassivatingContextWrapper.java:61) [weld-core-impl-2.0.3.Final.jar:2013-07-17 09:29]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:76) [weld-core-impl-2.0.3.Final.jar:2013-07-17 09:29]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79) [weld-core-impl-2.0.3.Final.jar:2013-07-17 09:29]
    at org.bpmnwithactiviti.cdi.bean.BookOrder$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getIsbn(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363) [javax.el-3.0-b07.jar:3.0-b07]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140) [javax.el-3.0-b07.jar:3.0-b07]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204) [javax.el-3.0-b07.jar:3.0-b07]
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226) [javax.el-3.0-b07.jar:3.0-b07]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.0.3.Final.jar:2013-07-17 09:29]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.0.3.Final.jar:2013-07-17 09:29]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:115) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:115) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:115) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1896) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:451) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219) [jsf-impl-2.2.1-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    ... 29 more
```

The page is a simple form used to start the new Activiti process.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <f:metadata>
            <!-- bind the key of the process to be started -->
            <f:viewParam id="processDefinitionKey" name="processDefinitionKey" />
        </f:metadata>

        <h1>New book order</h1>
        <h:form>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>ISBN:</td>
                    <td><h:inputText value="#{bookOrder.isbn}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><h:commandButton value="Submit"
                            action="#{businessProcess.startProcessByKey(processDefinitionKey)}" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

And the bean, referenced from the jsf is bellow:

```
package org.bpmnwithactiviti.cdi.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.inject.Named;

import org.activiti.cdi.annotation.BusinessProcessScoped;

@BusinessProcessScoped
@Named
public class BookOrder implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String isbn;
    private boolean approved;

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public boolean isApproved() {
        return approved;
    }

    public void setApproved(boolean approved) {
        this.approved = approved;
    }
}
```